# "NameError: name api_key is not defined" when parsing json

Tags: json, syntax, api-key

I'm completing an assignment and having a little bit of trouble. (Very new to this)  I am receiving "***NameError: name api_key is not defined***" message. The syntax in this cell is as follows:

```
record = 0
for index, row in location_data.iterrows():
    city_name = row['city']
    country_code = row['country']
    url = target_url + city_name + ',' + country_code + '&units=' + units + '&APPID' + api_key
    print (url)
    try: 
        weather_response = req.get(url)
        weather_json = weather_response.json()
        latitude = weather_json["coord"]["lat"]
        longitude = weather_json["coord"]["lon"]
        temp = weather_json["main"]["temp"]
        humidity = weather_json["main"]["humidity"]
        cloud = weather_json["clouds"]["all"]
        wind = weather_json["wind"]["speed"]
        location_data.set_value(index,"Temp", temp)
        location_data.set_value(index,"Humidity",humidity)
        location_data.set_value(index,"Wind Speed", wind)
        location_data.set_value(index,"Cloudiness",cloud)
        location_data.set_value(index,"Lat", latitude)
        location_data.set_value(index,"Longitude",longitude)
        print("Retrieved data for %s, %s" % (city_name, country_code))
    except:
        print("No data for %s, %s" % (city_name,country_code))
    record += 1
    if record % 59 == 0:
        time.sleep(60)
```

Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

In the line `url = ...`, you are using a variable called `api_key` which is not defined.